# Show the Fourier series converges pointwise to $f$, without using the fourier coefficients.

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Consider the Fourier series of the function $f(x)= \frac{\pi}{4}|sin(x)|$.
>
> - Show the Fourier series converges pointwise to $f$
> - Calculate the Fourier coefficients of $f$
> - Prove that the Fourier series converges uniformly on  $\mathbb{R}$ to $f$

I'm stuck on trying to prove that the Fourier series converges pointwise, without calculating the coefficients first.

I did manage to do the last two questions, but I don't know how I can start the first one without using the coefficients.

Comment: Have you seen the fact that if f is a Hölder function then it's Fourier series converges pointwise everywhere to f?

Comment: @RagibZaman Sorry, I have not seen that (yet)

Comment: No need to be sorry. Basically, to prove pointwise convergence we usually need to put some bound on the magnitude of the Fourier coefficients. There are some standard results that bound these magnitudes based on how "well behaved" the function is, such as being Holder continuous, but you can also make these estimates directly for a specific function. However, this will probably feel like going most of the way of calculating the coefficients and stopping just short with a bound (my rough calculation is $\hat{f}(n) \sim C/n^2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be proved, that Fourier series $S(x)$ of piecewise smooth function on $(-\pi, \pi)$ converges pointwise to the following value:

$$
\begin{aligned}
S(x) &= \frac{f(x+0)+f(x-0)}{2},\ \forall x \in (-\pi, \pi)\\
S(-\pi) = S(\pi) &= \frac{f(\pi-0)+f(-\pi+0)}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Fortunately, $f(x+0) = f(x-0) = f(x),\ \forall x \in (-\pi, \pi)$, so that

$$
S(x) = f(x), \forall x \in (-\pi, \pi)
$$

Since $f(\pi-0) = f(-\pi+0) = 0$

$$
\begin{aligned}
S(\pi) &=  0 = f(\pi)\\
S(-\pi) &= 0 = f(-\pi)
\end{aligned}
$$

Because of periodicity

$$
S(x) = f(x),\ \forall x \in R
$$

Comment: But if you define $S(x)=\frac{f(x+0)+f(x-0)}{2}$, you always get that $S(x)=f(x)$?

Comment: @Peggy_B Yes, that's right. In fact, you can demand, for example, $2\pi$ periodicity and absolute integrability on $[-\pi, \pi]$, existence of $f(x+0), f(x-0), f'(x-0), f'(x+0)$ and still obtain the same result. I have mentioned conditions that are enough to solve your problem. Btw you need to check in lectures/relevant literature how this theorem is formulated and how it can be derived.